# How to render File object to HTML element (using Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm having some problems rendering an image in a HTML element. I think the solution might be simple for experienced front end devs.
I have a Vuetify component that lets user input a profile image:

```
<v-form>
   <v-avatar size="144">
       <v-icon hidden ref="default_icon" size="144">account_circle</v-icon>
       <img ref="my_img" style="display: none;" :src="my_photo.name">
       <v-btn @click="$refs.my_input.click()" class="img_btn" absolute right small fab dark color="pink">
           <v-icon dark>add</v-icon>
       </v-btn>
       <input ref="my_input" hidden type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onFileChange($refs.my_input)">
   </v-avatar>
</v-form>
```

When the element calls onFileChange it pass the HTML element to the function.

```
onFileChange(event) {
    this.my_photo = event.files[0]
    console.log(this.my_photo)
    this.$refs.default_icon.style.display = "none"
    this.$refs.my_img.style.display = "inline"
}
```

So now the function replaces the icon with the img tag. I want to fill the image tag with the image that the user inputs. this.my_photo is a File type variable.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Regards for everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my_photo.name` is literally just the name of the uploaded image.  You need to convert the uploaded image to a valid format for the image `src`.

You can do this a couple ways using either [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) or [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).  These create source representations that the image tag can use.

Keep in mind that if you plan on uploading this image to a server you will need to keep a reference to `event.target.files[0]`.

Here an example using `URL.createObjectURL()`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    my_photo: '',
  },
  methods: {
    onFileInput(event) {        
      const data = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      this.my_photo = data;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" @change="onFileInput($event)">
  <img :src="my_photo" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i was looking for. I really appreciate it.